# I want to show that $(x_1-\alpha_1,...,x_k-\alpha_k)$ is a prime ideal over the ring $K[x_1, ...,x_n]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, $x_1,...,x_n$ indeterminates and $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \in K$. We have the ring $R=K[x_1,...,x_n]$ and the ideal $I_k = (x_1-\alpha_1,...,x_k-\alpha_k)$, for any $k \in \{1,...,n\}$. To prove that the ideal $I_k$ is prime, I want to show that the integral domain $K[x_{k+1}, ...,x_n]$ is isomorphic to $\frac{R}{I_k}$.

I tried to define a ring homomorphism
$$ \psi : K[x_{k+1}, ...,x_n] \longrightarrow \frac{R}{I_k} $$
as $\psi (f) = f+I_k$. I've been able to show that is a well-defined homomorphism and it is injective. I know that, if I show that it is surjective, I have the ring isomorphism. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I propose to use the substitution homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the easiest option is to define an inverse map instead of proving injectivity/surjectivity. Let $\alpha: R/I_k \to K[x_{k+1},\ldots, x_n]$ be defined by $\alpha(x_i) = \alpha_i$ for $i=1,\ldots, k$ and $\alpha(x_i) = x_i$ for $i=k+1,\ldots, n$. It should be quick and easy to show it is inverse to your map $\psi$.